# Scroll is bubbling from absolutely positioned popup to fixed position webpage layout

Tags: html, css

I have a web page layout that is created with position fixed when I open a full screen popup without overlay which is absolutely positioned and scroll over the popup the fixed positioned layout which is below the pop is scrolling I want to stop this behavior.

Comment: If you could add some of your HTML/JS/CSS code to demonstrate the problem, the community can better understand the problem.

Comment: Can you share what you have tried. Also, you need to provide additional details to make your question answerable

Comment: thank you guys i got my mistake thanks for immediate assistance